# Is there any instinct to know whether a method is going to give you back an iterator or a pair?

Tags: c++, iterator

I've noticed that there are a number of methods in C++ where you get something back and its members are accessible via `.first` and `.second` while there are a number of other methods that give back an iterator where you must use `->first` and `->second`. In both cases you're actually just looking at a `std::pair` but the difference is just whether you got an iterator or a reference to the pair.

Is there any kind of intuition to know which of the two you are going to get. This is particularly bad when dealing with `std::map` and `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: Read the doc instead of guess ?

Comment: My instinct is to go to [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)

Comment: The instinct should be to point your browser at http://en.cppreference.com/w/ or similar.

Comment: @Jarod42 I am trying to understand if there is an underlying design principle that can help me intuit which I will be dealing with. It's not about being unable to read the docs.

Comment: @NickChapman Every standard container should be seen as holding elements of it's `value_type`. That's it. `std::map<T>::value_type` is `std::pair<const Key, T>`, so it's iterators refer to `std::pair<const Key, T>`s. That's about as far as the underlying design principles go.

Comment: The cases where `std::(unordered_)map` return just an `iterator` are when they are returning a reference to a specific item in the map. As the `value_type` of a map is a `std::pair`, you have to dereference an `iterator` (`->` or `*.`) to access the item's `first` and `second` fields. The cases where the maps return a `std::pair` by value are when they are returning 2 pieces of information related to the result of an operation. For instance, when `insert()` returns both a `bool` indicating whether a new item was added or an existing item was found, and an `iterator` to the new/found item.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to think of iterators as pointers. When you get back an iterator, the  usage is `iter->first`, `iter->second`, etc. When you get back a `value_type`, the usage is `item.first`, `item.second`.

This is clear when you iterate over the items of a map. If you use a regular `for` loop, you would use something like:

```
std::map<K,V> aMap;

....

std::map<K,V>::iterator iter = aMap.begin();
std::map<K,V>::iterator end = aMap.end();
for ( ; iter != end; ++iter )
{
   // Use iter->first for the key
   // Use iter->second for the value
}
```

When you use a range `for` loop, you would use something like:

```
for ( auto const& item : aMap )
{
   // Use item.first for the key
   // Use item.second for the value
}
```

Comment: So the answer is just when using a range based for loop you get back a reference to the pair (assuming `const auto&`) instead of an iterator

Comment: @NickChapman, when using a range `for` loop, you get back objects of type `contaner::value_type`. For `std::map,` those happen to be `std::pair<const T, V>`. If you iterate over the elements of `std::vector`, you get back objects of type `std::vector::value_type`, which happen to be `T`.

Comment: (Except of course when you use a range-for loop over a `T[N]`, as there's no such thing as a `T[N]::value_type`. See also `std::iterator_traits<Container>::value_type`)